# Laravel validator does'nt correctly validate file mime type

Tags: laravel, laravel-validation

I send multiple files to my server with postman
And these files are uploaded correctly but they are not properly validated before uploading

this is my controller

```
   public function store(Request $request)
    {
        // دریافت دایرکتوری مطالبه مربوطه :  $demand=Demand::find(72)->files->first()->file_directoryس
        //{"title":"this is test title","demandContent":"this is test content "} send as form-data request
        //------------------------------------------- Valid Uploaded File ---------------------------------
        $rules = array(
            'file'  => 'required',
            'file.' => 'mimes:doc,pdf,docx,zip,jpg,jpeg,rar'
        );
        $error = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);
        if($error->fails())
            return response()->json(['errors' => $error->errors()->all()]);
        //-------------------------------------------- Valid Uploaded File -------------------------------
        $request->data=json_decode($request->data); //دریافت به صورت جیسون و تبدیل به شی
        $demand=new Demand(['title' => $request->data->title,'content'=>$request->data->demandContent,'user_id'=>auth('api')->user()->id]);
        if($demand->save()) //اگر درخواست در دیتابیس قبت شد
        {
            //----------------------------File Upload Scope---------------------------------------
            if($request->hasfile('file'))
            {
                $path='public/demands/'.$demand->id.'/files';
                foreach($request->file('file') as $file)
                {
                    $filename=$file->getClientOriginalName();
                    $file->move($path, $filename);
                }
                $demand->files()->save(new File(['file_directory'=>$path]));
            }
            //----------------------------File Upload Scope---------------------------------------
            return response()->json(['demand'=>new DemandResource($demand)],200);
        }
        return response()->json(['state'=>'false']);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

In your validation rules you have forgotten `*` like:

```
$rules = [
    'file'  => 'required',
    'file.*' => 'required|file|mimes:doc,pdf,docx,zip,jpg,jpeg,rar',
];
```